# Why does a conductor shield its inside from its outside, but not vice versa?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

A point charge outside a hollow conducting sphere will produce no field in the hollow interior: the metal shields the interior. But a point charge inside the hollow interior *will* produce a field outside: the same metal ceases to act as a shield.

Why is this? Aren’t “inside” and “outside” just matters of perspective? Why can’t I think of the sphere as enclosing the rest of the Universe, instead of the small spherical region?

Comment: Haven't got the wording to describe it properly so: Something something fields can go around outside something something fields can't go around inside something something they have to go somewhere. Wish I could fill in the gaps but the wording just isn't coming to me

Comment: If you do a $1/r$ transform, points inside become points outside and vice versa. But if you do that, I think the laws of physics also get flipped (although I can't think how to prove that). But in the "normal" geometry, you have an inverse square law and Gauss's Law - and between them they define the behavior as we see it. After the geometry transformation I don't think the same laws apply.

Comment: There is a pretty solid discussion of this here using Gauss' law: http://faculty.uml.edu/cbaird/all_homework_solutions/Jackson_1_1_Homework_Solution.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Musing on this I've thought of one possible take on it.

If we assume a overall neutral universe, then every electric field line that starts on a positive charge ends on a negative charge somewhere and *vice versa*.

That means that there *are* charges outside the sphere in the case where we've put a change in the hollow, they've just been pushed off to Far Far Away. If we invert *that* case we don't get an empty interior, but one with charge on the inside too, and that admits non-zero fields on the inside.

A peace and order are restored to physicsland.

***If*** you are willing to admit the precondition.

Comment: Aaaa, but peace and order weren't restored to me. If we have, say, negative charges outside a Faraday cage, thy repel the electrons. Where go these electrons? Not to the interior surface of the cage? Then, since inside the metal the field is zero, (otherwise the charges would be in movement) the electrons don't produce a field inside the cage?